# Inserting Rows in Database Using Sqlite Iphone

Tags: iphone

I have the following code n i have 4 records in data base but loop is running 2 times n getting only first row two times whats a problem in my code?

```
- (void) getAllRowsFromTableName:(NSString *)tableName{
    NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM '%@'",tableName];
   
    NSLog(@"query is :%@",qsql);
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,[qsql UTF8String] , -1, &statement,nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSLog(@"loop");
            int catId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
             NSLog(@"***CatId is :%d",catId);

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
```

Comment: Try with commenting the sqlite3_finalize(statement); inside the while loop.

Comment: yes u r right by commenting the sqlite3_finalize(statement); inside the while loop my code is now working fine Thanks Ravin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just to complete and close this question I am putting my comment in answer.*

Try with commenting the sqlite3_finalize(statement); inside the while loop.
Explaination:

SQLite.org says

> The sqlite3_finalize() function is called to delete a prepared
>   statement.

Also,

> The application must finalize every prepared statement in order to
>   avoid resource leaks. It is a grievous error for the application to
>   try to use a prepared statement after it has been finalized. **Any use
>   of a prepared statement after it has been finalized can result in
>   undefined and undesirable behavior such as segfaults and heap
>   corruption.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Wow! Another that use sqllite3 natively!! :)

I would suggest you an external lib (2 files) named **FMDB**, that is a wrapper to `sqllite3`.

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Easy to use. Hope this helps.